# Javascript: How can i check if a array contains certain values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create something that can detect if multiple values are in a array, this is what I tried to use, but that always returns true

```
row7 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

var field = [row0, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7];
console.log(field[0,1]); // Get the first item in the array


    var needles = [1, 1, 1, 1]
    console.log(needles)
    var haystack = field[0,row7]
    console.log(haystack)

    console.log(contains(haystack,needles));
    function contains(haystack, needles) {

return needles.map(function (needle) { 
    return haystack.indexOf(needle);
}).indexOf(-1) == -1;
}
```

Case true:

```
row 7 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Checked for (four in a row):

```
needles =  [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

And false:

```
 row7 =  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Edit:

Entire array:

```
/*    Array containing the playing field 8 x 8 

       C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
    R0[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
    R1[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
    R2[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R3[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R4[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
    R5[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R6[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0] 
    R7[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

*\

```
    var row0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row6 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    row7 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

var field = [row0, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7];
```

Is there any way to achieve this using plain JS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is row0...row6?

Comment: It seemed that `contains` mean one of value present in targeted array, it return true. Only when all value is not present in target array, it return false

Comment: @gurvinder372 added entire array.

Comment: so the consecutive items of needles should be contained in consecutive items of haystack?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `contains` method to

```
function contains(haystack, needles) 
{
   return haystack.join(",").indexOf(needle.join(",")) != -1;
}
```

**Explanation** -

- do a join of `needle` to get `"1,1,1,1"`
- and the join of haystack to get `"1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1"`
- when you do `indexOf` you will get 0 since needles is contained in haystack

Comment: That seems to work, thank you! 
So it returns 0 if it contains the needles, and -1 when it doesn't?

Comment: @user5301203 No, it returns -1 if haystack doesn't have needles. Otherwise it returns the starting position of needles

Comment: Another (kinda unrelated question), how can I use this to check a column, so for example the first one of row 1 to row 7?

Comment: @user5301203 I didn't get you

Comment: I added a graphic in my original post, I want to do the same thing for C0

Comment: @user5301203 that would require a different kind of solution. It was also not part of your original OP, so either check if this is already answered somewhere or kindly consider raising a different question for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest (not the most efficient) solution is to firstly convert both arrays into a string and then check if one string is a sub-string of another one:

```
function contains(array1, array2) { 
   if(array1 == null || array2 == null)
      return false;

   return array1.toString().contains(array2.toString()); 
}

var row7 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
var needles =  [1, 1, 1, 1];

contains(row7, needles); //returns true

row7 =  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

contains(row7, needles); //returns false
```

UPDATE:

I've just realized that `contains` function is not supported by all browsers. So it is better to use `indexOf` i.e. `return array1.toString().indexOf(array2.toString()) != -1;`

Comment: I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: array1.toString(...).contains is not a function

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: I use google chrome, also it is not row7 all the time, I just used that an example. It gets the rows ID passed from a parameter. looks like This:
`var haystack = field[0,row]`

Comment: I also use Chrome. Could you give an example how exactly do yo call my function?

Comment: `var haystack = field[0,row]
  var needles =  [1, 1, 1, 1];

  contains(haystack, needles);`

Comment: You must be using different version of Chrome than me. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) with an offset for the search.

```js
function check(haystack, needles) {
    var offset = 0;

    while (offset + needles.length <= haystack.length) {
        if (needles.every(function (a, i) {
            return haystack[i + offset] === a;
        })) {
            return true;
        }
        offset++;
    }
    return false;
}

var row7 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    row8 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    needles = [1, 1, 1, 1];

document.write(check(row7, needles) + '<br>');
document.write(check(row8, needles) + '<br>');
```